# Will regular backups make my hard drives fail early?

Tags: backup, hard-drive, hardware-raid

I have recently put in place Veeam Backup and Replication to do a nightly backup of a bunch of VMs running in VMware ESXi 5.1.  It appears that while Veeam generates incremental backups, it does so by reading everything on the disk and comparing.  It's hard to put a number on it but, given the light workloads of the VMs, I suspect that this increases the number of bytes being read by the hard drives in a month by at least a factor of 10.

Should I worry?  Is there a better way?  The hard drives are part of a hot-swap RAID system.

Comment: Perhaps so, but it'll be a lot less of a disaster than HDDs that fail less often but don't have any backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no need to worry. After all, Server HDDs are designed to be used all the time, and not only for reading but writing too.

Should you have decided to use non-server HDDs though, there *is* reason to worry, but not because of the backup but the fact these things aren't designed to be used in a 24x7 workload.

Comment: I always wonder how much of a real or advertised concern using desktop drives is. Granted, you don't have things like TLER, but other than that? I know heated discussions have been waged, just sayin :)

Comment: I am using SAS desktop drives.  The cost of server HDs for the 4TB storage I wanted was prohibitive, and I figured that the redundant array of Inexpensive drives would offer protection against failure.  The operational load on the drives is not high.

Answer (score -1):

To be clear, Veeam Backup & Replication has two methods for determining what has changed on a VM. Option 1, use CBT (Changed Block Tracking) this makes it so Veeam only has to request the changed blocks. If this is being utilized you will see "(CBT)" next the read line for each hard disk. Option 2, read the entire disk and determine what has changed. Veeam Backup & Replication will only failover to Option 2 if CBT breaks, or cannot be enabled. If CBT cannot be used generally a warning will be reported. In VMware there are two common reasons why CBT will not be used and not throw a warning. 1. If the VM is HW Ver 4 or less. 2. If a VM is being used a Proxy.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation. Flagged as spam and downvoted.

Comment: Thanks VeeamTipper.  This was a very useful answer for me, since avoiding the load in the first place is far better than managing its consequences.  I asked this question because I saw many GB of data being reported as read from disk during backups.  I now think this is because I have installed Veeam on my main file server, and I think it is being used as the proxy.  I cannot understand the downvotes because your answer is not trying to pursuade me to use Veeam (I already do).